# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id '[' as a subtype

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have an abstract class called Fruit and I put the `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` on it as follow:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "fruits")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = Apple.class, name = "sandbox.Apple"),
    @Type(value = FruitGroup.class, name = "sandbox.FruitGroup")
})
public abstract class Fruit {

    public abstract String getName();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fruit [getName()=" + getName() + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode() + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

And my derived class looks like this

```
@JsonTypeName("sandbox.Apple")
public class Apple extends Fruit {

    private String _name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }
```

======[UPDATED]======
I also have class FruitGroup that extends Fruit and contains Array of Fruit.

```
@JsonTypeName("sandbox.FruitGroup")
public class FruitGroup extends Fruit {
private Fruit[] _Fruit;
private String _name;
private String _category;

public Fruit[] getFruit() {
    return _Fruit;
}

public void setFruits(Fruit[] fruits) {
    _Fruit = fruits;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    _name = name;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return _name;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    _category = category;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return _category;
}
```

}

When I tried to deserialize the jsontext into Fruit object, I found the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id '[' as a subtype of `sandbox.FruitGroup`: known type ids = [FruitGroup, sandbox.Apple] at [Source: (String)"{"fruits":[["sandbox.Apple",{"name": "Apple"}]],"name": "Fruit Group"}"; line: 1, column: 11]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
```

The jsontext [UPDATED] actually was generated by jackson version 2.10.2 and I didn't put any JSON annotations on my classes formerly. After I upgrade the jackson version to 2.11.0, I also update my abstract class to put the JSON annotations in it. Then I tried to deserialize it by using jackson version 2.11.0, but I got an error instead. Could you guys help me to solve this issue?
Here's my jsontext

```
{
    "fruit": [
        [
            "sandbox.Apple",
            {
                "name": "Apple1"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "name": "Group of apples",
    "category": "Sweet fruit"
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect, it has some syntax errors, that's why you can't deserialize it

Comment: Have you found answer to this question? I am also facing the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72089765/7584240

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because in your json file you have `"fruits": []`, so you are associating *fruits* with an json array while in your abstract `Fruit` class you expect the `"fruits"` property referring to the name of the subclass you want to deserialize your json. So if you modify your json like below :

```
{
    "fruits": "sandbox.Apple",
    "name": "MyApple"
}
```

You can then deserialize it to the `Apple` subclass of the `Fruit` class:

```
Fruit fruit = mapper.readValue(src, Fruit.class);
System.out.println(fruit); //<-- Apple(_name=MyApple)
```

So you can either decide to change your json format to match your java classes or decide to change your java classes to match your json file.

Comment: Hello, thank your for answering my question. I'm sorry that I didn't post my question completely. I just updated it.

Comment: @dedelduel You are welcome,  but this is a totally new question, not an update.

Comment: the question remains the same. I just updated the story why I got this issue